# TS2339: Property 'connect' does not exist on type 'typeof extension'

Tags: typescript, google-chrome-extension, vuejs3

I am using typescript + vue 3 to develop a google chrome extension, when I add this code to vue 3 setup function:

```
let port = chrome.extension.connect({
      name: 'popup-name'
    })
```

shows error when compile:

```
ERROR in /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/reddwarf-translate-plugin/src/public/widget/translator/Translator.vue.ts
7:32-39
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/reddwarf-translate-plugin/src/public/widget/translator/Translator.vue.ts(7,33)
      TS2339: Property 'connect' does not exist on type 'typeof extension'.
```

I have already add the chrome types, this is is the package config:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@types/chrome": "^0.0.177",
    "sass": "^1.49.0",
    "vue": "^3.2.29",
    "vuex": "^4.0.2"
  }
```

why this error happen and what should I do to fix it? by the way, I am using [manifest v3](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/#overview) and the node version is 16. I have already tried:

```
npm install @types/chrome -D
```

add type config in the `tsconfig.json` like this:

```
"types": [
        "chrome",
        "node"
      ],
```

still did not work.

Comment: You've probably seen an outdated tutorial. Replace `extension` with `runtime`.

Answer (score 1):

The thing with types is that the issue could just be with your code editor. VS code gives these errors sometimes and restarting it usually fixes things.

Comment: surprisingly that worked for me! thanks